# xpath: write to a file

Tags: java, file, xpath

I'm developing Java code to get data from a website and store it in a file. I want to store the result of xpath into a file. Is there any way to save the output of the xpath? Please forgive for any mistakes; this is my first question.

```
public class TestScrapping {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, XPatherException {

    // URL to be fetched in the below url u can replace s=cantabil with company of ur choice
    String url_fetch = "http://www.yahoo.com";

    //create tagnode object to traverse XML using xpath
    TagNode node;
    String info = null;

    //XPath of the data to be fetched.....use firefox's firepath addon or use firebug to fetch the required XPath.
    //the below XPath will display the title of the company u have queried for
    String name_xpath = "//div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()";

     // declarations related to the api
    HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
    CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties();
    props.setAllowHtmlInsideAttributes(true);
    props.setAllowMultiWordAttributes(true);
    props.setRecognizeUnicodeChars(true);
    props.setOmitComments(true);


    //creating url object
    URL url = new URL(url_fetch);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); //opening connection
    node = cleaner.clean(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));//reading input stream

    //storing the nodes belonging to the given xpath
    Object[] info_nodes = node.evaluateXPath(name_xpath);
   // String li= node.getAttributeByName(name_xpath);


//checking if something returned or not....if XPath invalid info_nodes.length=0
    if (info_nodes.length > 0) {

        //info_nodes[0] will return string buffer
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        {
            for(int i=0;i<info_nodes.length;i++)
                System.out.println(info_nodes[i]);
        }
        /*str.append(info_nodes[0]);
        System.out.println(str);
 */
     }

 }
 }
```

Comment: What is the [output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html) of your XPath expression?

Comment: @McDowell Object[] info_nodes = node.evaluateXPath(name_xpath);

Comment: `evaluateXPath` is not a standard Java library method. State what libraries you are using. Update your question with more detail.

Comment: @prasad whenever you add details, add it to the original question itself. Also, add link to the libraries that you are using (in this case `htmlcleaner.jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "simply" print the nodes as strings, to console/or a file --
example in Perl:

```
my $all = $XML_OBJ->find('/');    # selecting all nodes from root
foreach my $node ($all->get_nodelist()) {
    print XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($node);
}
```

note: this output however may not be nicely xml-formatted/indented

Answer (score 0):

The output of an XPath in Java is a nodeset, so yes, once you have a nodeset you can do anything you want with it, save it to a file, process it some more.

Saving it to a file would involve the same steps in java that saving anything else to a file involve, there is no difference between that and and any other data. Select the nodeset, itterate through it, get the parts you want from it and write them to some kind of file stream.

However, if you mean is there a Nodeset.SaveToFile(), then no.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take the NodeSet, which is a collection of Nodes, iterate on it, and add it to a created DOM document object. 
After this, you can use the [TransformerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html) to get a Transformer object, and to use its transform method. You should transform from a [DOMSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMSource.html) to a [StreamResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html) object which can be created based on FileOutputStream.